# Serving service worker file in src in Vite dev mode

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, vite, service-worker

I'm creating a Vite, React project and using FCM.

I have a `src/firebase-messaging-sw.js` service worker file that accesses environment variables via `import.meta`. The FCM SDK attempts to fetch the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file at the root level via `GET http://localhost:5173/firebase-messaging-sw.js`.

I tried configuring Vite's dev server proxy to serve `src/firebase-messaging-sw.js` for requests to `/firebase-messaging-sw.js`. Now I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module (at firebase-messaging-sw.js:1:8)` for the `GET http://localhost:5173/firebase-messaging-sw.js` request.

How can I fix this while keeping the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file in the src folder?

```
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/firebase-messaging-sw.js": {
        target: "http://localhost:5173/",
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => (
          path.replace(
            /^\/firebase-messaging-sw.js/,
            "/src/firebase-messaging-sw.js"
          );
        ),
      },
    },
  },
  build: {
    target: "es2022",
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        "main": "./index.html",
        "firebase-messaging-sw": "./src/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: (chunkInfo) => {
          return chunkInfo.name === "firebase-messaging-sw"
            ? "[name].js" // Put FCM service worker in root
            : "assets/[name]-[hash].js"; // Other main app JS in `assets/`
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

There's a similar reddit posting [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/18fj4zp/how_do_you_handle_sensitive_variables_with_a/).

It seems most Firebase API keys are safe to hard code and env variables will ultimately still be exposed in the client. But I'd still like to use env variables instead of hard coding to avoid saving the values in the repo.